# Number of substrings of string which has three vowels

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, substring

I participated in a coding challenge on hackerearth , and i was asked the following question .

> Alice and Bob are playing a game in which Bob gives a string SS of length NN consisting of lowercase English alphabets to Alice and ask her to calculate the number of sub-strings of this string which contains exactly 3 vowels.

This is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


class TestClass1{
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(line);


    String stringArray[]=new String[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int len = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        stringArray[i]=br.readLine();     
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      System.out.println(determineNumberOfSubstring(stringArray[i]));
    }


}
public static int determineNumberOfSubstring(String str)
{
    int numberOfSubstring=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        int ctr=0;
        for(int j=1;j<str.length()-i;j++)
        {
             String subString = str.substring(i,i+j);
             if(subString.length()<3)
             {
                 continue;
             }
            if(subString.contains("a")||subString.contains("e")||subString.contains("i")||subString.contains("o")||subString.contains("u")
                ||subString.contains("A")||subString.contains("E")||subString.contains("I")||subString.contains("O")||subString.contains("U"))
            {
                ctr+=3;
            }
        }
        if(ctr==3){
            numberOfSubstring++;
        }

    }
    return numberOfSubstring;
}
```

}
Iam getting time limit exceeded for the above code . Could any one help me out on how to optimise it .

**Update1**

Code as per @GhostCat logic , this needs to be tested and is not the final code.

```
class TestClass1{
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
    String stringArray[]=new String[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int len = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        stringArray[i]=br.readLine();     
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      System.out.println(determineNumberOfSubstring(stringArray[i]));
    }
}
public static int determineNumberOfSubstring(String str)
{
    int numberOfSubstring=0;
    int ctr=0;
    int subStringStart=0;
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(isVowel(str.charAt(i)))
            ctr++;
        if(ctr==3)
        {
            numberOfSubstring++;
            ctr=0;
            if(s.empty())
                s.push(str.substring(0,i));
            else
                s.push(new String(s.peek().substring(1,i+1)));
            i=str.indexOf(s.peek().charAt(1))-1;
        }
    }
    return numberOfSubstring;
}
private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
     if(c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u'
             ||c=='A'||c=='E'||c=='I'||c=='O'||c=='U')
         return true;
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: @ghostcat i appreciate your help , currently iam in a medical emergency . I will get back to this as soon as i can .

Comment: Some thoughts on your updates: using `isVowel()` is a clear improvement, as your code is now easier to read, too. You could check if it is "better" to use Character.toLowerCase() for example; that cuts the number of comparisons by half. Or as said, create a `Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('A, 'a', ...))` and use its contains() method. I have to admit I dont get the full scope of your stack solution ( I am not sure if you need that - so you could look into making that even shorter ;-) ... finally: keep in mind that this is not a tutor service; so: when you have more

Comment: questions, then please ask a new question (or we talk about me giving tutor advise for upvotes else-where ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: your code is iterating the whole substring for each and any lower and upper case vowel there is. And that happens in a loop in a loop.

Instead: use ONE loop that goes over the characters of the input string. And then check each position if it is a vowel by checking against a set of characters (containing those valid vowels). The final thing you need: a simple "sliding" window; like: when you spot three vowels, you can increase your counter; to then "forget" about the first of the three vowels you just found; like in:

```
a x e y i --> vowels a/e/i give one substring
  x e y i ... and you look out for the next substring e/i/... now
```

Actual implementation is left as exercise to the reader ...

Long story short: this count can be computed by processing your input ONCE. Your code is iterating countless times more than once. Well, not countless, but N * N * some more.

( the one thing to be careful with: when using a `Set<Character>` be precise when you turn a `char` value into a`Character` object; you want to minimize the instances of that happening, too; as that is a rather expensive operation )

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat . Explanation is very intuitive and clear . Iam posting whatever i have coded till now . This is not tested , will update the same as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

HAPPY CODING ######                                 (if useful then upvote)

Que: count possible substring contain exactly 3 vowel in given string
my approach in O(n):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

        string s;
        cin>>s;
    vector<long long int>idex;

    idex.push_back(-1);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='a' || s[i]=='e' || s[i]=='i' || s[i]=='o' || s[i]=='u')
        {
            idex.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    idex.push_back(n);
    if(idex.size()<5)
    {
        cout<<0<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        long long int ans=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=idex.size()-4;i++)
        {
           ans+=(idex[i]-idex[i-1])*(idex[i+3]-idex[i+2]);
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
}
```